# Python map element with character

Tags: python

I am new to python and i am trying to understand the map() function.  Is there a better way of doing this

```
 map(lambda x: x+"+" ,map(str,range(5)))
 output : ['0+', '1+', '2+', '3+', '4+']
```

Comment: `['{}+'.format(x) for x in range(5)]`

Comment: This is fairly opinion based.  Some people are against using `map()` and don't consider it pythonic, some do.

Comment: Define "better." I mean, the double `map` call is kind of redundant. (You could just encode the `str` call directly in the `lambda` function.) But you could do it this way or a list comprehension. Either are fine. Is there something in particular that you're confused about with the `map` function? You seem to understand what it does.

Comment: If you insist on using lambda, at least do it with a single map `list(map(lambda x: "{}+".format(x),range(5)))`

Comment: Fun with category theory: `map(f, map(g, xs)) == map(lambda x: f(g(x), xs)` for pure functions `f` and `g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `format`-Method directly as `map`-argument:

```
map("{}+".format, range(5))
```

Comment: This is a markedly trivial change. No real improvement for a string operation this simple.

Comment: This is a significant improvement for performance reasons, as it replaces the user-defined function with one implemented in C.

Comment: @chepner The list is 5 elements long. The performance gains are insignificant.

Comment: Yes, because `map` will never be used for a list of more than 5 elements.

Comment: @jpmc26: the main point is, that you need a callable, and normally one thinks at first at `lambda`, but there are better ways, by using methods directly.

Comment: Also, the question clearly states that the OP is trying to understand the `map` function; don't fixate on the exact example they are using to do so.

Answer (score 1):

For most tasks like this, it is preferable to use a list comprehension, like so:

```
[str(i) + '+' for i in range(5)]
```

Here, you are constructing a list with each element depending only on the number `i`. Using `str(i) + '+'` is then one way to build the elements that you want. Another is `'{} +'.format(i)`, but that is beside the point of using a list comprehension.

#### map vs. list comprehension

The `map` function is functionally equivalent to a restricted use of the list comprehension syntax. Consider the following generic examples, which will produce the same output:

```
list(map(fun, iterable))
[fun(el) for el in iterable]
```

In your example, you construct the function `fun` right there inside the `map` call using a `lambda` expression. The additional `list()` call is necessary in Python 3, as `map` returns a generator and not a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you want in Map, You can map something like this:

```
print(list(map(lambda x:str(x)+'+',range(5))))
```

output:

```
['0+', '1+', '2+', '3+', '4+']
```

Additional info :

map() is a function with two arguments :

```
map(g, iterable)
```

first argument function is a function and the second a sequence.

Python 3 map is equivalent to the generator expression

```
(g(x) for x in iterable)
```

Comment: Minor quibble: in Python 3 `map` is equivalent to the generator expression `(g(x) for x in iterable)`, not the list comprehension.

Comment: @chepner thanks for info :)

Answer (score 0):

```
output = ['{}+'.format(i) for i in range(5)]
print output
['0+', '1+', '2+', '3+', '4+']
```

Comment: Some explanation would be very useful for the OP.

Comment: This doesn't explain the map function at all